# Can't resize Access 2007 Navigation Pane

Tags: ms-access-2007

I resized my A2007 Navigation Pane and somehow closed it up so tight (maybe 8 mm) that I can't resize it again (can't grab the right margin....) The pane is open and operates, I can type a search into the pane's search bar, and it works, including opening the object I find. I just can't get it to resize so I can read it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am finding this difficult to replicate, however, if you are comfortable with Windows API and VBA, I have a fairly mad partial solution.

Comment: Remou, I'd be interested in the idea (though I already solved the problem...)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Hit F11, to close the pane, then drag it out.

It is an infuriating problem!

Comment: That didn't work. It turned out to be an issue with the search bar. Close the search window and the darned thing becomes resizable again. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this problem with Access 2010 database saved in Access 2002 - 2003 format.  Click F11 to collapse the Navigation Pane.  Then select the edge of the collapsed navigation pane and drag to the right.

Answer (score 3):

Just had this Navigation Pane problem in Access 2010... infuriating is an understatement. Lost an hour trying to figure it out... lost a form that wouldn't save in the process.

With a database open,  goto: File/Options/Current Database/Navigation Options{button}/ De-select the "Show Search Bar".

Should be able to open the Database and expand the navigation pane, now.

Thanks.

Comment: Did nothing to help. There is just no double arrow that pops up when you move the cursor to the right edge of the navigation pane. F11 and toggling the search bar does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers did not work for me. This however worked.

Click on the Navigation pane title, "All Access Objects" in red. Change the objects you want to display. In my case I chose "Tables" from "All Access Objects". You can choose any.

Now drag the navigation pane out.

Change to the original display objects

Cheers.